# Swift Filter Nested Array

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSMutableArray` which it self has many arrays inside it. Inside each array at all index they further had custom objects of class given bellow.

```
Class User:NSObject{
    var name = ""
    var userName = ""
    var email = ""
    var age = 0
    var gender = ""
    var 
}
```

I want to filter this nested array with respect to two objects.
For example if user type some text in searchBar and check that text in that nested array if that text matches with the name or the userName or both.

Comment: Do you want to keep the nested hierarchy or have a flat [User] array returned?

Comment: I want to keep the nested Hierarchy that is the problem currently i am unable to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let textToSearch:String = "some text"

for nestedArray in myArray {

    for item:User in nestedArray
    {
        if user.name.contains(textToSearch) || user.userName.contains(textToSearch)
        {
            print("found")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Would this method search for text at any random range inside the string??
For Example if String contains "This is Mystical String To Search" and user have just type "tica" would this method get success for searching this string in above string?

Comment: yes that is correct it searches the entire string for all ranges and if it matches then returns true. So with your example it would find the text. Another example is the name was "Mark Blogs" and you searched for "log" this would find it.

Comment: Ohh.. Thank you sir. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 11):

```
let nestedArray: [[User]] = [[user1, user2], [user3], [user4, user5]]

let searchName = "foo"
let filteredArray = nestedArray.map({
        return $0.filter({ $0.name == searchName })
    }).filter({ $0.count > 0 })
```

This is a purely functional way that results in a new nested array that only contains arrays with matching users and these arrays also will only contain the matching users.

Answer (score 6):

A few suggestions

### A struct is a better fit for a model value

```
struct User {
    let name: String
    let userName: String
    let email: String
    let age: Int
    let gender: String
}
```

### Don't use NSMutableArray

`NSMutableArray` is an Objective-C class. You can access it via Swift but you should use the Swift array struct. It is faster and, being a value type, prevents bugs related to multiple parts of your code accessing a shared object.

### Filtering your data

Now given an array of arrays of `User`

```
let data: [[User]] = ...
```

and a keyword

```
let keyword: String = ...
```

your can filter your data writing

```
let matchingUsers = data
    .flatMap { $0 }
    .filter { $0.name.range(of: keyword) != nil || $0.userName.range(of: keyword) != nil }
```

Now `matchingUsers` is an array of `User(s)` where the `name` or the `username` contains the `keyword`.

Comment: So I understand better, are you calling `.filter` on what's being returned from `.flatMap { $0 }`?

Comment: @random: with `flatMap { $0 }` I transform an `array of arrays of User` (so this `[[User]]`) into an array of `User` (this `[User]`).

Comment: @random: __YES__, the output of `flatMap` is processed by `filter`

Comment: I see. Then the filter is _only_ returning `Users` that meet the criteria hints the `-> Bool`.

Comment: @random: By the way there was an error in my code, now it's fixed.

Comment: awesome, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

A slightly improved version of what matteok suggested:

It makes sense to ignore register in such filtering, and instead of checking equality check if lookup target contains search query

Also using `!$0.isEmpty` is more swifty than checking for `$0.count > 0`

```
let nestedArray: [[User]] = [[user1, user2], [user3], [user4, user5]]

let searchName = "foo".lowercased()
let filteredArray = nestedArray
  .map { $0.filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchName) }}
  .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more "swiftly" way to go about doing this using the `filter(_:)` method provided by `Array`.

Method:

```
func filter(_ isIncluded: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Element]
```

Implementation:

```
    // Create some generic objects to test on
    let object1 = User()
    object1.name = "John"
    object1.userName = "jdoe"

    let object2 = User()
    object2.name = "Jane"
    object2.userName = "jdoe"

    let object3 = User()
    object3.name = "Bob"
    object3.userName = "bjones"

    // Add them to a test array
    var objects = [[]]
    objects.append([object1])
    objects.append([object2])
    objects.append([object3])

    // What we want to search on
    let searchString = "j"

    // Filter the array
    for array in objects {
        let searchedSubArray = array.filter {
            return $0.name.rangeOfString(searchString, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch)     != nil ||
                   $0.userName.rangeOfString(searchString, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil

        }
        if (searchedSubArray.count > 0) {
            print("we found a match!")
        }
    }
```