# Filtration coredata model in tableView

Tags: swift, core-data, filter, set, filtering

I have two models in my Coredata like:

```
CountryCD {
 @NSManaged public var id: Int16
 @NSManaged public var title: String?
 @NSManaged public var cities: NSSet?
}
```

and

```
CityCD {
 @NSManaged public var id: Int16
 @NSManaged public var title: String?
 @NSManaged public var country: CountryCD?
}
```

and showing it in tableView with some quantity of sections and rows
`country[section].cities[indexPath.row]`

I'm trying to add filtration in tableView
code for this right now is:

```
*
let filtered = countries
    .compactMap { (($0.cities as? Set<CityCD>)?
                    .filter { $0.title?.lowercased()
                        .contains(text.lowercased()) ?? false } ?? []) }
    .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
```

and it work almost how I need, it gives me `[[CityCD]]`, but I need `[CountryCD]` to show filtration result in my tableView.
Can someone help me to figure out how to fix this?

- source [Swift Filter Nested Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595393/swift-filter-nested-array/39595725)

Comment: `let filtered = countries.filter { aCountry in guard let cities = aCountry as? Set<CityCD> else { return false } return cities.contains(where: ( aCity in return aCity.title?.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased()) ?? false )} }` might do the trick.

Comment: @Larme you meant `let cities = aCountry.cities ...` I assume

Comment: Indeed. Compiling in my head will always have flaws ^^

Comment: Do you really want an array of countries, shouldn’t it be every matching city for each country, so more like a dictionary?

Comment: I would have also expect a "shorten" of the cities which aren't in the list. Sample: Country: US, cities: "New York", "Atlanta", "Las Vegas", searching "n" should let Las Vegas appear?

Comment: @Larme yeah, much better then I wrote before, but result gives me all cities in Country, if that country contains city with text.lowercased() :( trying to find where is bug  in tableView maybe, but don't found yet(

Comment: @Larme ye< this solution gives me all set of cities if country have city that contain `searchingText`  Any way if someone need this code here is correct punctuation `filteredCountries = countries.filter { aCountry in guard let cities = aCountry.cities as? Set<CityCD> else { return false } return cities.contains(where: { aCity in eturn (aCity.title?.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased()) ?? false ) }) }`

Comment: Hope someone can help with with this one 

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks man your proposal saved me) populated that tableView with dictionary and filtration is so easy.. xD thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If anyone will face problem aka I did, here is solution I reached with help of @Joakim Danielson clue

in `model`:

```
var countriesDict: [CountryCD: Set<CityCD>]
var filteredCountriesDict: [CountryCD: Set<CityCD>]
```

when `populate`:

```
countryDict = savedCountries.reduce([CountryCD: Set<CityCD>]()) { [$1: $1.cities as? Set<CityCD> ?? [] ] }

filteredCountryDict = [:]
tableView.reloadData()
```

in `numberOfSections`:

```
return isFiltering ? filteredCountryDict.count : countryDict.count
```

in `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
return isFiltering ? Array(filteredCountryDict)[section].value.count : 
                     Array(countryDict)[section].value.count
```

in `cellForRowAt`:

```
let dictionary =  .isFiltering ?
            Array(filteredCountryDict)[indexPath.section] :
            Array(countryDict)[indexPath.section]
        
let cities = (dictionary as NSSet).allObjects as? [CityCD]
cell.textLabel?.text = cities?[indexPath.row].title
```

when `filtering`:

```
let text = searchingText?.lowercased()
    .trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) ?? ""

isFiltering = !(text == "")

if isFiltering {
    countryDict.forEach { (key, value) in
        self.filteredCountryDict[key] = value.filter({$0.title?.lowercased().contains(text) ?? false})
    }
}else{
    filteredCountryDict.removeAll()
}

tableView.reloadData()
```

hoping would be useful