# Filtering a SectionedFetchRequest in SwiftUI on iOS15

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, ios15

I am trying to implement the new iOS 15 `SectionedFetchRequest` with Core Data. This allows you to change the predicates and sort descriptors at runtime.

My model has a `Group`, which can contain many `Item`s.

I declare the fetch request like this, then assign to it in the view's `init` method, so that I can apply a custom `NSPredicate` depending on where the view is being shown.

```
@SectionedFetchRequest private var mySections: SectionedFetchResults<String, Item>
```

The they are displayed in a `ForEach` loop, similar to the code from the [WWDC 2021 session](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10017).

```
var body: some View {
    // Other code
    List {
        ForEach(mySections) { section in
            Section(header: Text(section.id) {
                ForEach(section) { item in
                    Text(item.name) // Just an example
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am also implementing the `.searchable` view modifier, to provide search functionality. This is bound to a string variable like this.

```
@State private var searchText: String = ""
```

Then in the `body` property I use `.searchable($searchText)` on the bottom of the list.

---

This all works without issues. However, the problem comes when I try to use the search text to filter my results at runtime. I tried using a dynamic predicate instead and changing the fetch request predicate (compounded with the one from initialisation), but this proved very buggy (maintaining the search state when the view popped to a detail view was very difficult and led to details views popping unexpectedly).

So, I decided to filter the fetch request in runtime with standard Swift code. I have done this before easily with a one-dimensional array. However, `SectionedFetchRequest` is not just a two-dimensional array; it is a generic struct with `Section` and `Element` types and the section has an important `id` property (used to define the section heading).

Standard two dimensional filtering (such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39595393/swift-filter-nested-array) does not work, as the types are lost and you merely get a two-dimensional array.

I can easily get the sections that have an item that fits the search, but this returns all of the items in the section (rather than just the ones that fit the search):

```
mySections.filter { section in
    section.contains(where: checkItemMethod())
}
```

---

I tried to then make my own type that conformed to `RandomAccessCollection` (required by the `ForEach`) that I could populate recursively, but this seems very complex as there are so many "sub-protocols" to conform to.

Is there a way to easily filter a `SectionedFetchRequest` based on the inner objects, and only returning sections containing objects that match?

Thanks

---

#### EDIT

Here is my view init code. The `SelectedSort` type is straight out of the WWDC video. I just persist the `by` and `order` values in User Defaults.

```
init(filterGroup: DrugViewFilterGroup) {
        
    self.filterGroup = filterGroup
    
    // This relates to retrieving persisted value of the SelectedSort type demonstrated in WWDC
    let sortBy = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "sortBy")
    let sortOrder = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "sortOrder")
    let selectedSort = SelectedSort(by: sortBy, order: sortOrder)
    let sectionIdentifier = sorts[selectedSort.index].section
    let sortDescriptors = sorts[selectedSort.index].descriptors
    
    // Create sectioned fetch request
    let sfr = SectionedFetchRequest<String, Item>(sectionIdentifier: sectionIdentifier, sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: filterGroupPredicate(for: filterGroup), animation: .spring())
    
    // Assign fetch request to the @SectionedFetchRequest property of the view
    self._mySections = sfr
}
```

This all works just fine. The `filterGroupPredicate(for:)` method just returns an NSPredicate to show a subset of data.

The issue is with implementing the search bar with the `.searchable` modifier. This is bound to `@State private var searchText: String`.

Here is an example function filtering the results by the search text:

```
private func getFilteredSections() -> [SectionedFetchResults<String, Item>.Section] {
    let cleanedFilter = searchText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    guard !cleanedFilter.isEmpty else { return mySections.map { $0 } }
    
    func checkItem(_ item: Item) -> Bool {
            return item.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(cleanedFilter) 
    }
        
    return mySections.filter { section in
        section.contains(where: checkItem)
}
```

This works, but the problem is it only returns the "top level" i.e. the sections themselves. If a section contains a single item meeting the search criteria, all items in the section will still be returned.

Filtering it like a multidimensional array (as noted in original question), results in a simple 2D array with no section information to display in the nested `ForEach`, and thus the functionality of the `SectionedFetchRequest` is lost.

I tried setting the fetch request predicate (to a compound predicate based on the one set in `init` and one for the search text). This works briefly, but as the view is reinitialised on e.g. navigating to a tapped detail view, it results in erratic search bar behaviour.

Comment: You just create an `@objc` variable. Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69121593/shape-data-from-core-data-into-plottable-format/69131192#69131192) without any specifics we can provide a sample. Your question is very vague.

Comment: Hi @loremipsum and thanks for responding. I do use `@objc` variables for my section headers. I have maybe focused too much on my Core Data Stack, making the question less clear. I want to filter the resulting `SectionedFetchResults` in code based on what the user types into the search field. This will reference some properties on the object, which is fine, but it is the actual filtering that I have trouble with - e.g. using `mySections.filter { }` returns the sections, but I cannot filter the contained items as it just returns an array without a section identifier.

Comment: you are still being too vague. Give specifics. What is in the body of the `filter`? What exactly are you expecting. I can point you to the CoreData concurrency video from WWDC21 but without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @loremipsum Yes I based my code on that video. The one change was that I needed to assign a predicate to the sectioned fetch request in the `init` method. That all works. I can easily filter a multidimensional array with `.filter {}`, but here I need to filter the sectioned results in real time (based on user entering text in the search bar) but with maintaining the sectioning. I'll add more details in an edit to my question.

Comment: @loremipsum I have made an edit.

Comment: I don’t really see why you need to make this so complicated, if I have a sectioned fetch request together with .searchable it shows the section(s) that has at least one matching item and only those items that are matching. Maybe I am missing something here, why can’t you use the examples from Apple as a template for this?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson For me, doing exactly that filters the sections, but it returns everything in those sections, not just the items that match. Is there some way to link `searchable` directly to the `SectionedFetchRequest`?

Comment: You shouldn't filter the sections but the items.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried that, but it results in returning just a nested array `[[Item]]` with no section ID. The type (`SectionedFetchResults`) is lost in the filtering. You cannot construct a `SectionedFetchRequest` or its `Section` type as there are no accessible initialisers.

Comment: Well I don't know anything about that since I am using the simplest, most straightforward solution possible based on Apples samples and they work perfectly fine.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks. I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

`SectionedFetchResults` has a property `nsPredicate`. If you set that with your desired `NSPredicate(format:)`, the results are updated more or less immediately.

Works with SwiftUI search with something like:

```
mySection.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@", searchText)
```

Most of the other code can be erased. You need a little magic to manage displaying the filtered collection.

[SectionedFetchResults > nsPredicate in Apple Dev Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/sectionedfetchresults/nspredicate?changes=__4)