# Using NSPredicate to filter / unfilter sections in a SectionedFetchRequest

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm ordering my data and fetching into sections by using `SectionedFetchRequest`. I built a filter button that is supposed to filter all data where its priority is 0 (it is saved as `int32` and update a `list`.

After reading [Apple's Predicate Format Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html), I tried the following:

```
sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priorityText CONTAINS[c] %@", "Today")
sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priority == %@", 0) //**
sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priority like %@", 0)
sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priorityText == %@", "Today")
sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priorityText like %@", "Today")
sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priority == %@", 0 as NSInteger) //**
sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priority == %@", 0 as Int32) //**
```

The ones with the comment `//**` didn't crash, but filtered all out.

I went and read a few question here at SO (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69654020/filtering-a-sectionedfetchrequest-in-swiftui-on-ios15)) and [other sources](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/38/7/examples-of-using-nspredicate-to-filter-nsfetchrequest) (and [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-filter-core-data-fetch-requests-using-a-predicate) and [this about predicateWithFortmat](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate/1587997-predicatewithformat)) trying figure out how to filter integers out. But nothing I try works.

Also, I can't figure out how to *unfilter* data...

Entity

[image]

My code:

```
extension Task {
    @objc
    var priorityText: String{
        var result = ""
        switch self.priority {
        case 0: result = "Today"
        case 1: result = "Important Tasks"
        default: result = "All Others"
        }
        return result
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @SectionedFetchRequest(entity: Task.entity(),
                           sectionIdentifier: \.priorityText,
                           sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Task.priority, ascending: true)],
                           predicate: nil,
                           animation: Animation.linear)
    var sections: SectionedFetchResults<String, Task>
    
    @State var filtered = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(sections) { section in
                    Section(header: Text(section.id.capitalized).fontWeight(.bold).foregroundColor(.primary)) {
                        ForEach(section) { task in
                            Text("\(task.tasktext!)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Button(action: {
                        filtered.toggle()
                        if filtered {
                            // check https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html
                            //sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priorityText CONTAINS[c] %@", "Today")
                            //sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priority == %@", 0)
                            //sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priority like %@", 0)
                            //sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priorityText == %@", "Today")
                            //sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priorityText like %@", "Today")
                            sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priority == %@", 0 as NSInteger)
                        } else {
                           print("unfilter?")
                        }
                    }) {
                        Label("Filter", systemImage: filtered ? "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle.fill": "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle").foregroundColor(.primary)
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The answer to the first question, how to filter data based on an integer, is:

```
sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priority == %i",0)
```

And to display the unfiltered data:

```
sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priority >= %i",0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question:

To filter:

```
sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priority == %i",0)
```

To unfilter:

```
sections.nsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "priority >= %i",0)
```